# Is it possible to delete the oldest segment in Lucene?

Tags: solr, lucene

I want to keep the specific number of segments by deleting older segment.
It is possible in Lucene or Solr?

Comment: Are you sure you understand what you are asking for? Why would you delete a segment with valid data? Why not delete the oldest documents and merge?

Comment: Whats your goal? Do you want to delete oldest documents? Do you know what optimize means in context of Solr?

Comment: I thought deleting the oldest segment is lighter than deleting documents and merging/optimizing indices. All I want is limiting the max number of docs in my index.

Comment: Or is it possible to treat multiple indices as a single index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from *[Lucene in Action](http://www.manning.com/hatcher3/)*

> Each index file carries a certain type of information essential to Lucene. If any index file is modified or removed by anything other than Lucene itself , the index becomes corrupted, and the only options is to run the CheckIndex tool [...] or perform a complete reindexing of the original data.

So in short: No, you yourself cannot.

---

But you can influence Lucene/Solr to keep an eye on the segments for you. Interesting for you should be these topics.

## Merge Factor

Taken from the solrconfig.xml of Solr's example collection1

> The merge factor controls how many segments will get merged at a time.
> For TieredMergePolicy, mergeFactor is a convenience parameter which
> will set both MaxMergeAtOnce and SegmentsPerTier at once.
> For LogByteSizeMergePolicy, mergeFactor decides how many new segments
> will be allowed before they are merged into one.
> Default is 10 for both merge policies.

Further reading

- https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors#Configuration_Considerations

## Merge Policy

Also taken from the solrconfig.xml of Solr's example collection1

> The Merge Policy in Lucene controls how merging of segments is done.
> The default since Solr/Lucene 3.3 is TieredMergePolicy.
> The default since Lucene 2.3 was the LogByteSizeMergePolicy,
> Even older versions of Lucene used LogDocMergePolicy.

Further reading

- http://juanggrande.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/merge-policy-internals/

## Merge Scheduler

Also taken from the solrconfig.xml of Solr's example collection1

> The Merge Scheduler in Lucene controls how merges are
> performed.  The ConcurrentMergeScheduler (Lucene 2.3 default)
> can perform merges in the background using separate threads.
> The SerialMergeScheduler (Lucene 2.2 default) does not.